# MySQL extremely slow under Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, performance, osx-snow-leopard

I've installed MySQL 5.1.40 Source distribution (64-bit executable x86_64) following these [instructions by Hivelogic](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/) and the mysql (2.8.1) gem using ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" .

I'm using it for Ruby on Rails development and my problem is that even if MySQL is working in every way, it is extremely slow.
Take this comparison with sqlite3 when performing a standard rake db:migrate creating about 15 tables.

MySQL:

> time rake db:migrate
>   real 0m4.882s
>   user 0m1.426s
>   sys 0m0.235s

sqlite3:

> time rake db:migrate
>   real 0m2.282s
>   user 0m1.501s
>   sys 0m0.255s

One also has to consider that about 1.5s of the execution time on each test is loading of the rails framework which means that sqlite3 performs the SQL tasks in about 0.5-1s while MySQL requires more than 3s for the same set of tasks.

Isn't that just plain wrong? What can be the cause of this? Anyone experiencing the same problem?

I have installed and re-installed mysql and mysql/ruby gem several time but always with the same outcome... :(

My Snow Leopard installation is an upgrade and not a fresh installation. Might that be the cause of the problem? Some outdated library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the data in your question, it sounds like you are comparing bananas to oranges.

Specifically, do you have any evidence that the results are even out of line?  Comparisons with other platforms running the same tests?

Is this even a test that is relevant to whatever you eventually want to do?  I.e. are you testing something that is relevant to the typical set of tasks you will normally be doing or trying to optimize for a one-off task that happens during setup?

Note also that SQLite and MySQL have radically different performance profiles.  SQLite is a single-user, non-client/server, database whereas MySQL is typically configured to act in a client/server role.  Beyond totally different performance profiles, this also leads to completely different scalability characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for your response bbum!
The only comparison I have with another platform is that I ran the same test suit (that uses the above db:migrate) under Leopard and it is now significantly slower under Snow Leopard with execution time taking about 1 min in Leopard and about 3-4 min in Snow Leopard.

I've also noticed that mysql seems to "choke" which didn't happen under Leopard. If I try to insert 200 records - the first 30-40 goes lightning fast (~0.8ms) but then it slows down drastically to ~200ms per insert even though the complexity between the first inserts and the last ones is the same.

Comment: OK-- I would suggest using `sample` on both Leopard and Snow Leopard to get a sort of overview where the CPU cycles are going. This may also be due to disk syncing changes between the two OSes.  In any case, it is common to need to tune a database to a particular system.